# Multiple query with iDB2DataAdapter

Tags: db2, dataadapter

I am trying to run multiple statements in an iDB2DataAdapter and I do not know what separator to use for between SQL Query Statements or even if you can run multiple statements like with SQL Server.

Using the System iNavigator (SQL Server Management Studio for DB2) "Run SQL Scripts" functionality (Query Analyzer), you can run multiple query statements when you separate them with a semicolon ";". That does not work with the iDB2DataAdapter.

If you terminate the first command with a ";", it returns the error:"SQL0104 Token ; was not valid. Valid tokens: ."

Replacing the ";" with "END-OF-STATEMENT" returns the error:"SQL0199 Keyword END not expected. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE."

Putting "BEGIN" and "END' around statements did not help.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks, Mike

Comment: I don't know what is iDB2DataAdapter, but normally you can only issue a single SQL statement via a dynamic SQL interface, like JDBC or ODBC, and such a statement should not have a terminator (because it's not part of the statement). Having said that, a compound SQL statement (the one that has `BEGIN ... END`) **is** a single SQL statement and it normally works if you get the syntax right, which you apparently did not. It's hard to give you a better answer since you have not provided any meaningful details about your DB2 platform, version, or the statements you tried.

Comment: Also, this behavior is usually a security hole - it's usually what SQL Injection needs to do the really nasty stuff.